# Raw strings with re.search()?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn how to do python regular expressions. I want the following program to search for the string 'N\S\A' in the input string.  I read ([here](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions?csw=1)) that you have to make strings raw strings if you want to deal with '\' characters. But I put the r in front of the match string and it's still not working. (Whether inword is 'NSA' or 'N\S\A'...)

```
import re
inword = input('Enter in text that may or may not be suspicious: ')
print("Inword is:", inword)
mword  = re.search(r'N\S\A',inword)
if mword :
    print('Matched',mword .group())
    #deployDrones();
else:
    print('Not matched')
```

Why isn't this working? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regular expression.

Use `in` operator:

```
>>> inword = 'Hello N\S\A!'
>>> r'N\S\A' in inword
True
```

If you really need regular expression, you need to escape `\` itself, because `\S` match non-space character (`\A` also has special meaning):

```
>>> inword = 'Hello N\S\A!'
>>> re.search(r'N\S\A', inword)
>>> re.search(r'N\\S\\A', inword)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f804ea33370>
```

> \S
>
> When the UNICODE flags is not specified, matches any non-whitespace
> character; this is equivalent to the set [^ \t\n\r\f\v] The LOCALE
> flag has no extra effect on non-whitespace match. If UNICODE is set,
> then any character not marked as space in the Unicode character
> properties database is matched.
>
> \A
>
> Matches only at the start of the string.

from [Regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: Fair enough...but what would I do if I HAD to use regular expresion?

Comment: Oh, ok thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: but why do you think putting an `r` before the regex not do the same job? Isn't it asking python to consider the elements in regex as literal characters?

Comment: @user1993, Using raw string is to make the escape `\ ` in Python string. Regular expression itself also require escaping. Please read [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (the second paragraph mentions it.)

Answer (score 2):

To include a backslash as a character without any special meaning in a regular expression, you have to escape it with another backslash.

In your case, you should use:

```
mword  = re.search(r'N\\S\\A',inword)
```

Raw strings make python treat backslash as an ordinary character, but it still has a special meaning in regular expression.